# Image viewer in web (Pan, Zoom & Draw polygon)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I want to develop a web-form which can enable my clients to:

- Zoom on image
- Pan image
- Draw some polygon overlays on the zoomed and panned image

Any JavaScript libraries? Any solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by saying _a web-form_? web-form project? You added _asp.net-mvc_.

Comment: That's right, a web-form project.